# What's the overhead of forward-when-no-consumers in Hornetq?

Tags: hornetq

Motivation: I am trying to settle a design for my HornetQ messaging system and I want to avoid setups which would introduce lots of additional network roundtrips between cluster nodes and possible lockups.
If there's a lot of overhead I would build a system ensuring connections to all nodes. Of course I would like to rely on the parameter and avoid the additional work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would transfer a message through the clustered queues without the need. that's the overhead. If you don't have a consumer on the other node is better that the message is not transferred at all.

Redistribution would eventually send the message back to where it's needed. But that's an unnecessary round trip.

Comment: My concern is that for every message the receiving server is contacting all other servers to check if there are consumers - that's the roundtrips and overhead I am concerned about. I want to be able to push a huge number of non-persistent messages.

Comment: You could disable cluster connections for these queues?

Comment: It's funny that we used to keep messages always at the current node..  we didn't want to do load balancing at all.. but there was a strong request from lots of users to do load balancing.

We should add an option in a near future

Comment: So as I take it the communication with other nodes is happening for every message. Thanks for the info!